# Vtiger error message "Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file." and illegal request

Tags: crm, vtiger

I am trying to migrate from one server with vTiger 6.0 to a new server with vtiger 6.2.
I complete the installation and also i move the database from the old server and no problems in those parts.
The errors come when i try to login, if i try to login with my user i get the error

```
"Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file"
```

and when i try to login with the admin account i get a lot of illegal request messages, i do get the vTiger GUI but if i click in one option menu i get a illegal request and if i logout it displays the next message

```
"{"success":false,"error":{"code":"Illegal request","message":"Illegal request"}}"
```

i'm new to Vtiger and i don't know why is this happening.
Some extra info i have try to check the path directory and seems to be right, the database data is right too it recognize the users when you log in just doesnt show anything but an error.
When i finish the installation i could enter with no problem the problem start when i uploaded the Database.
Also i want to access to enter from another computer, do i need to enable port 8888 on the server?
I am using a localhost and from that pc i want to acces from another pc.

Answer (score 3):

If you've migrated your data then try checking /vtiger/user_privileges/

There should be 2 files for each user: user-privileges-*.php and sharing-privileges-*.php (admin will be 1)

These can become lost and/or have dodgy permissions after migration, has happened twice to me. For some reason, Admin always copies over and works.

From your backup, take the related user files in /vtiger/user_priveleges/ and put them in new working folder and set permissions to read/write.

Comment: despite all of the other suggestions out there, this is exactly what had happened to me.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Illegal  request  error is due to the improper CSRF validation. Please make sure that  your browser  url is same as your  $site_URL in  config.inc.php file .

config.inc.php file you will get from your Directory following below path --
C:\Program Files (x86)\vtigerCRM620\apache\htdocs\vtigerCRM\config.inc.php

In that file change $site_URL from 'http://localhost:8888/';   to 'http://1.6.2.12:8888/';  (1.6.2.12 is your machine IP)

This process will make your machine "1.6.2.12" into server for Vtiger application, so your application will be hosted on server 1.6.2.12 and then you can access this application on other computer also.

Port-8888 is used by Apache which is inbuilt in Vtiger by default so don't make any changes in that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you transfer all files in `/user_privileges` because they are generated by sharing rules system in vTiger should be transferred like database.